# Is it possible to change the IP of docker container when it is running?

Tags: containers, docker, openstack

I need to change the IP and port of a running docker container. Is it possible? If so How??

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know. You should solve that on your host by setting up routing. Not really my area of expertise, but can you use something like http://www.computerhope.com/unix/route.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the IP address but remain on the Docker bridge (i.e. Docker assigned 172.17.0.10 and you want 172.17.0.13), you can manually change it, but you shouldn't — because Docker will not "know" about it, and you will certainly run into problems (it will eventually re-use the address that you assigned, leading to address conflicts), and port mapping won't work anymore (since Docker will still send traffic to the old address).

If you want to add another network interface to a Docker container, to connect the container to a specific network, you can use [Pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework), since that's exactly what it does.

However, it would be even more interesting to explain why you want to change the IP address — there might be a better solution in the first place :-)

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail? with the help of commands ?? About how to change manually ? Is it possible to change ip of live container ??

Comment: @brotherofmysister In my environment, I want to save a docker image and port it to another machine that does not have internet access (so I want to use downloaded dependencies) and has a different set of host nodes. Essentially I would like to perform --add-host after starting the container from the image. I tried this but it doesn't update the /etc/hosts file in the container. `docker exec -d <container> /bin/bash "printf '192.168.2.20\thostname20.com\n' >> /etc/hosts" `